# JIT optimization preventing techniques

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, jit

In `java-8` sources we can find quite tricky way of JIT optimization inside class `Class`:

```
/*
 * Private constructor. Only the Java Virtual Machine creates Class objects.
 * This constructor is not used and prevents the default constructor being
 * generated.
 */
private Class(ClassLoader loader) {
    // Initialize final field for classLoader.  The initialization value of non-null
    // prevents future JIT optimizations from assuming this final field is null.
    classLoader = loader;
}
```

So, this constructor is never invoked, but JIT will be "cheated" by this trick.

My question is: could it be implemented in slightly different way, let's say

```
private Class() {
    classLoader = (ClassLoader)(new Object());
}
```

This is absolutely meaningless logic, but does it matter if constructor will never been invoked?

**Would such kind of trick also prevent JIT from this optimization?**

Comment: I can't exactly imagine that it's used in anything less than native code, specifically because it's not a type-safe constructor.

Comment: @Makoto `classLoader` field you mean?

Comment: No, I mean this private constructor.  I can find no uses of it in any Java library and I doubt that us mortals would want to use it since it's not a type-safe `Class` instance.  Remember:  `Class` is defined as `Class<T>`.

Comment: My apologies, but how is this fact related to my question? I'm asking about ways about how does JIT optimization preventing work?

Comment: OK, I'm going to remove part of question about `volatile`, it seems to be little bit silly

Comment: To all interested, I've dramatically changed my question to emphasize main question about JIT optmitization preventing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 6 and Java 7 (and Java 8 before update 40), the constructor is as simple as `private Class() {}`, but in these versions, there is no `classLoader` field either.

This implies that the association between `Class` and `ClassLoader` had to be maintained in a special JVM specific way, thus, `getClassLoader()` has to call into a `native` method, not necessarily involving JNI, but rather handled as a JVM intrinsic operation, but still requiring special care inside the JVM’s native code. Further, the garbage collector had to know about the special relationship.

In contrast, hiding a field in Reflection is not so complicated, while now having an ordinary field simplifies the JVM’s native code, most notably the `getClassLoader()` operation and the garbage collector implementation(s). It might also be simpler for the optimizer to inline field accesses if it’s an ordinary field.

---

Now, when the `Class` objects are created via special JVM code, not using the declared constructor, it could contradict an optimizing JIT’s assumptions made by analyzing the constructor’s actual code to predict the possible values for this `final` field.

Note that nobody said that the current JIT is that smart. The comment talks about hypothetical “*future JIT optimizations*”. Having a constructor initializing the field with a parameter value is in line with what the JVM actually does.

In contrast, a constructor like your suggested `classLoader = (ClassLoader)(new Object());` could lead a hypothetical optimizer to conclude that this field can’t be initialized with an actual `ClassLoader` instance as that code can never complete normally.

Comment: It seems like earlier versions of Java 8 also didn't have the `classLoader` field. It [used a `native` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getClassLoader0%28%29).

Comment: @4castle: seems it has been added exactly in update 40.

Answer (score 0):

The commentary in the source of `Class` states that the initialisation value  make future JIT optimisation **knowing that the `classLoader` field is not null.** So the optimizer might do an even better job in future.

To prevent optimisation, just declare your fields `volatile`.